Implementing Retry Logic with Backoff and Cancellation in C# Asynchronous Tasks
I have a service which runs as a background job. It's duty is to try and hit some external service for some external update. Now, I am to attempt retrying an HTTP request against the service for a specified number of times. Ultimately, after the third try, I am to backoff for a few minutes, and try one more time. The service should return on failure of the fourth try.
My service roughly looks like this:
private async Task DoSyncCustomerProfile(SyncMessage message)
{
    foreach (var customerProfile in message.CustomerProfilesDto)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cancellationToken = cts.Token;

        //create a task responsible for syncing data
        Func<Task<RequestResponse<SomeResponse>>> task = async () =>
        {
            var url = $ "https://google.com/v1/abcdefhj";
            var response = await _requestService.Post<SomeResponse>(
                url,
                customerProfile,
                nameof(SomeOperation),
                _auth,
                "Bearer"
            );
            return new RequestResponse<SomeResponse>
            {
                Data = response.Data,
                Successful = response.Successful,
                Message = response.Message
            };
        };

        var response = await AttemptUpdate(task, cancellationToken, _options.Value.MaxRetries);

        if (!response.Successful)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Setting backoff time for {BackoffTime} minutes", _options.Value.BackoffTime);

            //set the backoff time here
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_options.Value.BackoffTime), cancellationToken);

            var url = $ "https://google.com/v1/abcdefghij";
            var responseFromRetry = await _requestService.Post<SomeResponse>(
                url,
                customerProfile,
                nameof(SomeAction),
                _auth,
                "Bearer"
            );
            _logger.LogDebug("Response from retry --> {Response}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseFromRetry));
            response = new RequestResponse<SomeResponse>
            {
                Data = responseFromRetry.Data,
                Successful = responseFromRetry.Successful,
                Message = responseFromRetry.Message
            };

            if (!response.Successful)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Failed to sync profile after 3 attempts. Skipping.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

For some weird reason, my service never hits _logger.LogDebug("Response from retry --> {Response}", although the condition for failure is true.
This is how my retry function is:
private async Task<RequestResponse<SomeResponse>> AttemptUpdate(
        Func<Task<RequestResponse<SomeResponse>>> task,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        int maxAttemptCount = 3)
{
    for (var attempted = 0; attempted < maxAttemptCount; attempted++)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Attempt {Attempted} to sync customer profile with Star Assurance", attempted + 1);

        // Check for cancellation
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Cancellation requested. Exiting retry loop.");
            return new RequestResponse<SomeResponse>>
            {
                Successful = false,
                Message = "Operation cancelled"
            };
        }
        var result = await task();
        _logger.LogDebug("Received response --> {Response}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));

        // Result is successful so we can return
        if (result.Successful)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Succeeded to sync customer profile with response --> {Response}", result.Data?.Message);
            return result;
        }

        _logger.LogDebug("Failed to sync customer profile with response --> {Response}", result.Data?.Message);
    }

    return new RequestResponse<SomeResponse>>
    {
        Successful = false,
        Message = "Failed to sync customer profile"
    };
}

I have a feeling the introduction of asynchronicity is causing something I cannot detect. Or am I managing the threads wrongly? My desired goal is to return when the attempt post backoff fails. My backoff of 10 minutes does not run, but what happens is the list is iterated over again and enters AttemptUpdate again.

I'd really look into Polly before rolling my own. So, do you prefer finding the bug in this implementation or reaching the desired outcome even if it means ditching 95% of this?

I think I might look at Polly if I am not able to figure out what is happening here. I am not sure how fundamental the error I am making here is. @Fildor

Can you exclude swallowed exceptions? From looking at the code, I cannot see anything obvious (to me).

Why do you bother with a cancellation token when there do not seem to be any way to actually cancel it? I would also add exception handling. If you do not get the log rows you expect, chances is that there is an exception thrown.

Agree with the above comment. I'm assuming you're using HttpClient inside your _requestService. It's important to know that HttpClient will throw an exception in some circumstances - including a timeout - which you need a try/catch block for. You can't just rely on checking the response status code, because it will never arrive. Currently, the unhandled exception means that your code method above will immediately exit, so it'll never get to your logging statements.
